# Java Program Deletion (Mac/Linux)

Tags: java, linux, macos, operating-system, delete-file

How would I make my Java application delete itself and then close out of itself on a Mac/Linux OS? I have tried a couple `Runtime` commands, but none of them seem to work.

Something like this maybe:

```
try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "rm \"" + getRunningJarPath() + "\""});
} catch (final IOException e) {}
```

Note: The method: `getRunningJarPath` IS accurate.

Comment: You see, I am running a Windows computer. I want to make COMPLETE SURE that this code will work for Macs/Linuxes.

Comment: If you want to be sure, test on the platforms.  Linux runs well in vmware player.

Comment: I was just wondering if someone could just take 5 mins to test it for me so that i dont have to spend 1000+ dollars on a mac?

Comment: Use Java WebStart and let the JVM manage it itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, it's not possible: you program may happen not to have rights to remove itself.

Additionally, there's a problem: while your program is running, JVM holds a read lock on the JAR, so it well may be that you cannot delete it right away.

Usually, you run your program from a script which would check the exit code and remove the files if necessary.

Comment: Unix based systems allow for files to be removed while open.

Comment: It depends on the underlying filesystem, as far as I can tell—and you don't know in advance which filesystem is there.

Comment: No, it depends on the operating system.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a cron job to delete file, that will start after a delay

Comment: try {
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "rm \"" + getRunningJarPath() + "\""});
 System.exit(0);

} catch (final IOException e) {}

Answer (score 0):

You do not state why you want the program to be deleted afterwards.

Anyway, you should not rely on manipulating the file system yourself.  I would suggest you look into Java WebStart instead as it provides all the file system caching (including expiration) you need.